# Google ChromeでHTMLとCSSをモバイル表示をさせたときの画面サイズが異常です。

Tags: html, css

**現象**
Google Chromeのモバイル表示を320×568pxに設定して、そのサイズに合わせたコード（HTMLとCSS）を書いていたのですが、VS CodeのLiveServer機能でGoogle Chromeのモバイル表示をさせると、980×1739pxの大きさになってしまいます。

[image: 当該画面のスクリーンショット]

**期待値**
Google Chromeのモバイル表示で、320×568pxの大きさで表示させること。

**再現手順**
下記のコードをGoogle Chromeのモバイル表示で実行すると再現できます。CSS設計の方式は、FLOCSSです。

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./foundation/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./foundation/grid.css">
    <title>Facebook</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="advice">
        <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
        <p>iPhone用Facebookで高速ブラウジング</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fbLogo">
        <img src="./img/image_0.svg" alt="某SNSのロゴ">
    </div>
    <div class="loginForm">
        <input class="telNumEmail" type="tel email">
        <div class="lineSpacing"></div>
        <input class="password" type="password">
        <div class="loginButton">
            <button type="button">ログイン</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="signUpButton">
            <button type="button">新しいアカウントを作成</button>
        </div>
        <div class="forgotPasswordLink">
            <a href="">パスワードを忘れた場合</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="localeSelector">
        <nav class="left-nav">
            <ul>
                <li>日本語</li>
                <li><a href="">Português (Brasil)</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Español</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Deutsch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="right-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">English (US)</a></li>
                <li><a href="">中文(简体)</a></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <nav class="footer-navi">
            <ol>
                <li><a href="">Facebookについて</a></li>
                <li>・</li>
                <li><a href="">ヘルプ</a></li>
                <li>・</li>
                <li><a href="">その他</a></li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
        <small>Facebook Inc.</small>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

`foundation/grid.css`

```
/* ページ全体の設定 */

body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 16px 287px 16px;
    grid-template-rows: [advice] 48px [fbLogo] 47.42px [telNumEmail] 42px [lineSpacing] 8px [password] 44px [loginButton] 52px [separator] 18px [signUpButton] 60px [forgotPasswordLink] 54px [localeSelector] 86px [footerNav] 22px [copyright] 17px
}


/* パーツの配置 */

.adviceArea {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: advice;
}

.fbLogo {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: fbLogo;
}

.telNumEmail {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    grid-row: telNumEmail; 
}

.lineSpacing {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    grid-row: lineSpacing;
}

.password {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    grid-row: password;
}

.loginButton {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    grid-row: loginButton;
}

.loginForm hr {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    grid-row: separator;
}

.signUpButton {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    grid-row: siguUpButton;
}

.forgotPasswordLink {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    grid-row: forgotPasswordLink;
}
```

`foundation/reset.css`

```
/* A Modern CSS Reset */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
figure,
blockquote,
dl,
dd {
    margin: 0
}

ul[role="list"],
ol[role="list"] {
    list-style: none
}

html:focus-within {
    scroll-behavior: smooth
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    line-height: 1.5
}

a:not([class]) {
    text-decoration-skip-ink: auto
}

img,
picture {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block
}

input,
button,
textarea,
select {
    font: inherit
}

@media(prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {
    html:focus-within {
        scroll-behavior: auto
    }
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        animation-duration: .01ms !important;
        animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
        transition-duration: .01ms !important;
        scroll-behavior: auto !important
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ビューポートの初期サイズを `meta` タグにより設定することで問題は解決すると思います。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./foundation/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./foundation/grid.css">
    <title>Facebook</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="advice">
        <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
        <p>iPhone用Facebookで高速ブラウジング</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fbLogo">
        <img src="./img/image_0.svg" alt="某SNSのロゴ">
    </div>
    <div class="loginForm">
        <input class="telNumEmail" type="tel email">
        <div class="lineSpacing"></div>
        <input class="password" type="password">
        <div class="loginButton">
            <button type="button">ログイン</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="signUpButton">
            <button type="button">新しいアカウントを作成</button>
        </div>
        <div class="forgotPasswordLink">
            <a href="">パスワードを忘れた場合</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="localeSelector">
        <nav class="left-nav">
            <ul>
                <li>日本語</li>
                <li><a href="">Português (Brasil)</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Español</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Deutsch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="right-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">English (US)</a></li>
                <li><a href="">中文(简体)</a></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <nav class="footer-navi">
            <ol>
                <li><a href="">Facebookについて</a></li>
                <li>・</li>
                <li><a href="">ヘルプ</a></li>
                <li>・</li>
                <li><a href="">その他</a></li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
        <small>Facebook Inc.</small>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```